# Wait until `this.state` has been set for time period before running function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I have a button, which has 3 states. Depending on which state is triggered, it should do a fetch to post this data.

Basically, I want it to wait until the `this.state.favourite` value has been set for more than 200ms. Then it should trigger the fetch.

It should never post multiple fetch's,

I tried using `_.debounce` of lodash, but it had no affect. It still ran the function immediately.

I also put it in a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/yarnball/pen/oZaprP?editors=1010).

```
class Switch extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
       favourite: 0
    }
  }

        handleClick() {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
       favourite: (prevState.favourite + 1) % 3
    }));
    return _.debounce(this.favChosen(), 1000)
  }
  favChosen(){
    if (this.state.favourite === 0) {
    return this.testConsole1();
  } else if (this.state.favourite === 1) {
    return this.testConsole2();
  } else if (this.state.favourite === 2) {
    return this.testConsole3();
  }
 testConsole1() {
    console.log('This will be a fetch 1')
  }
  testConsole2() {
    console.log('This will be a fetch 2')
  }
  testConsole3() {
    console.log('This will be a fetch 3')
  }
  render () {
    const { favourite } = this.state;
    const fill = favourite === 0 ? "grey" :
                 favourite === 1 ? "green" : "red";
    return (
        <button className="favStar" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} >
      <svg width="100" height="100">
        <g>
          <path id="svg_2" d="m0,38l37,0l11,-38l11,38l37,0l-30,23l11,38l-30,-23l-30,23l11,-38l-30,-23l0,0z" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="0" fill={fill} />
        </g>
      </svg>
            </button>
    );
  }
}

React.render( <Switch />, document.getElementById( "page" ) );
```

Comment: You can disable the button right after the button is clicked, then you don't need the `setTimeout`

Comment: Thanks, but that will not work. The user needs to be able to choose which number they give it (and may change it). I reworded question.

Comment: You can consider to apply throttle to `noFav`, `fav1` and `fav2`.  https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#throttle

Comment: Why do you want to wait 200ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You weren't using `debounce` correctly.

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
       favourite: 0
    }

    this.favChosen = _.debounce(this.favChosenRaw, 1000);     
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
       favourite: (prevState.favourite + 1) % 3
    }));

    this.favChosen()

  }
  favChosenRaw(){....
```

Working fiddle:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GmELKo?editors=1010

Answer (score 1):

A better solution to trigger an action on state change is to call the function on setState callback rather than waiting for a fixed time before calling the function. You never know how long it takes to change the state, also waiting for a sufficiently long time puts a limit to your application. Try this

```
class Switch extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
       favourite: 0
    }
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
       favourite: (prevState.favourite + 1) % 3
    }), () => {this.favChosen()});

  }
  favChosen(){
    if (this.state.favourite === 0) {
    return this.testConsole1();
  } else if (this.state.favourite === 1) {
    return this.testConsole2();
  } else if (this.state.favourite === 2) {
    return this.testConsole3();
  }
 testConsole1() {
    console.log('This will be a fetch 1')
  }
  testConsole2() {
    console.log('This will be a fetch 2')
  }
  testConsole3() {
    console.log('This will be a fetch 3')
  }
  render () {
    const { favourite } = this.state;
    const fill = favourite === 0 ? "grey" :
                 favourite === 1 ? "green" : "red";
    return (
        <button className="favStar" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} >
      <svg width="100" height="100">
        <g>
          <path id="svg_2" d="m0,38l37,0l11,-38l11,38l37,0l-30,23l11,38l-30,-23l-30,23l11,-38l-30,-23l0,0z" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="0" fill={fill} />
        </g>
      </svg>
            </button>
    );
  }
}

React.render( <Switch />, document.getElementById( "page" ) );
```

**[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WjOBGL?editors=1011)**

Comment: Thanks, but this had no affect. It still causes all testConsole's to run, and does not provide a buffer/wait time.

Comment: Check this codepen with my change, it only triggeres one testConsole http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WjOBGL?editors=1011